# Nested scroll not work when using Android compose with NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose, android-nestedscrollview

I have a parent **composable** that is scrollable and contains a child `AndroidView`. Inside the `AndroidView`, there is a `NestedScrollView`. I expected the child `NestedScrollView` to be able to scroll before the parent **composable**, but in reality, it is not able to scroll. Here is my code:

```
@Composable
fun TestScreen() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())

    ) {
        AndroidView(
            factory = {
                NestedScrollView(it).apply {
                    ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(this, true)

                    layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                    )
                    addView(TextView(it).also { tv ->
                        tv.layoutParams = ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        )
                        tv.text = "Inner scrollable"
                        tv.textSize = 100f
                        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.Blue.toArgb())
                    })
                }
            }, modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(200.dp)
                .clipToBounds()
        )


        Divider(color = Color.Red)
        Text(
            text = "Outer scrollable", fontSize = 50.sp, modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(800.dp)
        )
        Divider(color = Color.Red)
    }

}
```

I understand that I can add `verticalScroll` to the `AndroidView`, but that doesn't meet my expectations because it will make the `NestedScrollView` larger than the `AndroidView`. Currently, it's not an issue, but if I were to use a `RecyclerView` instead of a `NestedScrollView`, the items within the NestedScrollView wouldn't be recyclable, which would be a significant problem.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see,The `NestedScrollView` you've created as an `AndroidView` is not properly integrated with Jetpack Compose's `scrolling` system. You should use Jetpack Compose's own `LazyColumn` or `VerticalScrollbar` to achieve the desired nested scroll behavior.

Follow the code:

```
    @Composable
    fun TestScreen() {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {
            // Outer scrollable content
            Text(
                text = "Outer scrollable",
                fontSize = 50.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(800.dp)
            )

            Divider(color = Color.Red)

            // Inner scrollable content
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(200.dp)
            ) {
                items(50) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(50.dp)
                            .background(Color.Gray)
                    ) {
                        // Inner scrollable content
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Logic:

We are using `LazyColumn` to create a `scrollable` area for the `inner content`. The outer and inner content is organized within a `Column`, and Jetpack Compose's scrolling system handles the `nested scrolling` behavior automatically. This will give you the desired `nested scroll` functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I specifically require the EmojiPicker library provided by Google, which is currently implemented using Android View. The EmojiPicker includes a RecyclerView. Is there any alternative solution available in this situation?